# Custom Razor Html Attributes

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

With Razor html helpers it seems kind of poorly done to add custom html attributes.

I'm writing payment gateway integration and the card details need to be encrypted on the client's side.

Typical form field looks like

```
  <input type="text" data-eway-encrypt-name="EWAY_CARDNUMBER" />
```

I have tried to replicate this with

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Card.CardNumber, new { @class = "form-control", @data-eway-encrypt-name = "EWAY_CARDNUMBER" })
```

but no luck because it throws back

> CS0746: Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Can't you do this in JavaScript?

Comment: there must be a way to add the attribute in razor

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't have dash in property name. Use underscore instead, they will be automatically converted for you :

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(
    m => m.Card.CardNumber, new 
    { 
        @class = "form-control", 
        //@data-eway-encrypt-name = "EWAY_CARDNUMBER",
        data_eway_encrypt_name = "EWAY_CARDNUMBER",
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Use like below:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(
    m => m.Card.CardNumber, 
    new { 
        @class = "form-control", 
        data-eway-encrypt-name = "EWAY_CARDNUMBER",
    }
)
```

The `_` will automatically be converted to `-` in the resulting markup:

```
<input type="text" data-eway-encrypt-name="EWAY_CARDNUMBER" />
```